# Proguard exception while creating release android signed apk

Tags: android, proguard

I am using Google API for Google authentication in our project, but while making a release signed APK, we are facing some warnings such that we are not able to generate the signed APK. Please point out where the actual problem is.

```
[2013-06-01 10:32:01 - Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2013-06-01 10:32:01 - Note: there were 366 duplicate class definitions.
[2013-06-01 10:32:01 - Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient extends or implements            program class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
[2013-06-01 10:32:01 - Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R
[2013-06-01 10:32:01 - Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R$string
[2013-06-01 10:32:01 - Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil: can't find referenced class    com.google.android.gms.R$string
[2013-06-01 10:32:01 - Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R$string
[2013-06-01 10:32:01 - Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R$string
[2013-06-01 10:32:01 - Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R
[2013-06-01 10:32:01 - Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R$string
[2013-06-01 10:32:01 - Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R$string
[2013-06-01 10:32:01 - Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R$string
[2013-06-01 10:32:01 - Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R$string
[2013-06-01 10:32:01 - Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R$string
[2013-06-01 10:32:01 - Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R$string
[2013-06-01 10:32:01 - Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R$string
[2013-06-01 10:32:01 - Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R$string
[2013-06-01 10:32:01 - Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R$string
[2013-06-01 10:32:01 - Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R$string
[2013-06-01 10:32:01 - Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R$string
[2013-06-01 10:32:01 - Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can'tfind referenced class com.google.android.gms.R$string
[2013-06-01 10:32:01 - Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R$string
[2013-06-01 10:32:01 - Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced class 
[2013-06-01 10:32:01 - Warning: com.google.api.services.tasks.v1.Tasks$RemoteRequest: can't find referenced class com.google.api.client.http.HttpMethod
[2013-06-01 10:32:01 -  Warning: com.google.api.services.tasks.v1.Tasks$RemoteRequest: can't find referenced class com.google.api.client.http.HttpMethod
[2013-06-01 10:32:01 -  Warning: com.google.api.services.tasks.v1.Tasks$RemoteRequest: can't find referenced class com.google.api.client.http.HttpMethod
[2013-06-01 10:32:01 -Warning: com.google.api.services.tasks.v1.Tasks$RemoteRequest: can't find referenced class com.google.api.client.http.HttpMethod
[2013-06-01 10:32:01 -  Warning: com.google.api.services.tasks.v1.Tasks$RemoteRequest: can't find referenced class com.google.api.client.http.HttpMethod
[2013-06-01 10:32:01 - Warning: com.google.api.services.tasks.v1.Tasks$Tasklists$Delete: can't find referenced class com.google.api.client.http.HttpMethod
[2013-06-01 10:32:01 -  Warning: com.google.api.services.tasks.v1.Tasks$Tasklists$Delete: can't find referenced class com.google.api.client.http.HttpMethod
[2013-06-01 10:32:01 - Warning: com.google.api.services.tasks.v1.Tasks$Tasklists$Get: can't find referenced class com.google.api.client.http.json.JsonHttpParser
[2013-06-01 10:32:01 - Warning: com.google.api.services.tasks.v1.Tasks$Tasklists$Get: can't find referenced field 'com.google.api.client.http.HttpHeaders headers' in class com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse
```

Comment: Try adding this to your proguard-project.txt file:
-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
    protected Object[][] getContents();
}

Comment: make sure that before you relase your apk you must fully installed your app on device or emaulator.

Comment: @SharadMhaske  yes app is running on device

Comment: after complete installed then export signed Apk.check if its working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ProGuard: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18646899/proguard-cant-find-referenced-class-com-google-android-gms-r)

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution simple go inside android SDK tools/progaurd directory update all the jar files.

Comment: Could you clarify by specifying the steps you followed?

Comment: Download updated progaurd jar files then go inside progaurd directory replace all the jar files.

Comment: @ajit which progurd version you are using

Comment: @StinePike I am using 4.9