# Android : Cannot creating signed APK after enabling Proguard

Tags: android, build, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I just enable **proguard** in my project . After that i run the apk successfully by using **debug apk**.

When I try to creating a **signed Apk** am getting an error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:proguardRelease'.
 > java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

**My Gradle file like this**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.android4dev.navigationview"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
compile 'com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:1.3'
compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'

}
```

**Warning**

```
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzhu: can't find referenced class android.security.NetworkSecurityPolicy
Warning:there were 3 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
     You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
     If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
     the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
     (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
 :app:proguardRelease FAILED
  Error:Execution failed for task ':app:proguardRelease'.
  > java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

I tried `-dontwarn org.apache.lang.**`, but still am getting the same issue

Can any please help me to recover this problem.

Comment: use `minifyEnabled false`

Comment: @Binil S can u post your warnings?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I think he wants to enable proguard so `minifyEnabled` should be `true`

Comment: Yes that why i enable minifyEnabled as true @IntelliJAmiya

Comment: Update with warning , can you please check @Dinesh Kannan

Comment: I think you should first clear the issues that are shown at the error report....

Comment: I cleared all the warning that related to duplicate the permission, but still am getting error, that warning I updated in the question, can please help me @Opiatefuchs

Comment: have You cleaned Your project after deletnig the issues?

Comment: Yes. I sync the project and cleaned it, but still the same issue @Opiatefuchs

Answer (score 0):

For your google play services proguard problem refer here [com.google.android.gms.internal.zzhu: can't find referenced class android.security.NetworkSecurityPolicy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32974025/com-google-android-gms-internal-zzhu-cant-find-referenced-class-android-securi)

And also try to resolve the manifest duplication issues or you can disable lint in release build..
to disable the lint check in release build add this to your build.gradle file

```
lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
```

try updating the play services version in build.gradle

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0'
```

Comment: cleard all the duplicate permission in manifest  and try the above lint options but still I have the same issue@Dinesh Kannan

Answer (score 0):

According to the warning log that you have posted, it seems that the warning came from the package **com.google.android.gms.internal.zzhu** and not from **org.apache.lang**.

So to remove the warning add this in your proguard-rules.pro.

```
-dontwarn com.google.android.**
```

Tell us what happened then!