# Proguard unresolved references to classes

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-proguard

When building apk using Proguard, I see theses Warnings:

```
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaq: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzzk
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaq: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzzk$zza
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaq: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzzk
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaq: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzzk$zza
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaq: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzzk$zza
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaq: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzzk$zza
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaq: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzzk
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaq$1: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzzk
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaq$1: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzzk
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbd: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaqg
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbd: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzzk
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbd: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzzk
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbd: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaqg
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzej: can't find referenced field 'int[] AdsAttrs' in program class com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzej: can't find referenced field 'int AdsAttrs_adSize' in program class com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzej: can't find referenced field 'int AdsAttrs_adSizes' in program class com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzej: can't find referenced field 'int AdsAttrs_adUnitId' in program class com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
```

I'm using Google Play Services 10.2.0, modules ads, ads-lite, analytics, analytics-impl, base, basement, drive, games, tasks.

What modules or libraries need to be included to fix those warnings?

Answer (score 1):

Based from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18646899/proguard-cant-find-referenced-class-com-google-android-gms-r), if you use ProGuard, you need to keep some GMS (Google Play Services) classes and they are annotated with `@com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName`.

> You need to ignore like you are compiling but you also need to keep the class so it can find it during runtime.
>
> Add these two lines to your proguard configuration file:
>
> ```
> -keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
> -dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
> ```

You may also check these related SO posts:

- [Proguard and error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32596858/proguard-and-error)
- [com.google.android.gms.internal.zzhu: can't find referenced class android.security.NetworkSecurityPolicy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32974025/com-google-android-gms-internal-zzhu-cant-find-referenced-class-android-securi)
- [How to use -dontwarn in ProGuard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21123835/how-to-use-dontwarn-in-proguard)