# Generate Signed apk causing the Faced Note Error. How to fix this?

Tags: android, signed-apk

When i want to generate the signed apk. Then it is causing the error. The error log is showing below.

```
Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable'

Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'android.app.OnActivityPausedListener'

Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'com.mopub.nativeads.CustomEventNative'

Maybe you meant the fully qualified name 'com.google.android.gms.ads.mediation.customevent.CustomEventNative'?

Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'com.mopub.nativeads.CustomEventRewardedAd'

Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'Object'
      Maybe you meant the fully qualified name 'java.lang.Object'?
```

Comment: Have you used proguard?

Comment: Yeah. i am Using Proguard File with my dependencies is           classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'

Comment: in the proguard file you have to keep some files, proguard is kind of removing your classes to make small APK.

Comment: Check this link to add correct rule in proguard https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18646899/proguard-cant-find-referenced-class-com-google-android-gms-r/24109609

Comment: i followed by the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18646899/proguard-cant-find-referenced-class-com-google-android-gms-r/24109609 is Not worked for me... The Error is Repeated Again What I do.. Anyone help to me?